# how to define 'assert' in john resig's advance javascript tutorial

Tags: javascript

when I read john's tutorial,there're a lot of 'assert' & 'log' function, I know what they're capable of, but I don't know how to define these two functions.
I tried this, but failed.

```
    function assert(){return console.log;}
```

Answer (score 2):

`log` and `assert` are most likely just the same thing as `console.log` and `console.assert`. However, if you want the functions to be callable by `log` and `assert`, try the following:

```
function log(info){
    console.log(info);
}

function assert(info){
    console.assert(info);
}
```

Then you can use the functions as necessary:

```
> log('Hello World')
Hello World
> log('foo bar')
foo bar
> assert(5==6)
Assertion failed:
> assert(5==5)
```

Answer (score 1):

`assert` refers to this method from his book Secrets of the Javascript Ninja -

```
var output = document.getElementById('output'); 

function assert( outcome, description ) { 
    var li = document.createElement('li'); 
    li.className = outcome ? 'pass' : 'fail'; 
    li.appendChild( document.createTextNode( description ) ); 

    output.appendChild(li); 
};
```

as described [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-and-easy-javascript-testing-with-assert--net-14050).  I think the `log` is just a wrapper function for console.log that makes sure it is supported for that browser, like this -

```
function log(msg) {
    if (console && console.log) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement `assert` from scratch, you can do this:

```
function AssertionError(message) {
    this.name = "AssertionError";
    this.message = (message || "");
}
AssertionError.prototype = Error.prototype;

function assert(proposition, complaint) {
  if (!proposition) throw new AssertionError(complaint);
}
```

You can't really define `log` without falling back to `console.log`. Unless you "print" into a document.